# The product of an empty or all-NA Series is now 1. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

The version 0.22.0 of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) have introduced [a few backwards-incompatible changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html) when dealing with all-Na series.

Among the changes there is

> The product of an empty or all-NA Series is now 1

Why would this be better or have any advantage compared to returning NaN or 0? Isn't an error to return 1 on a product of NaNs? Can someone explain to me what is the deal here?

Comment: It is discussed at length is this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9422

Comment: @AlexRiley Thanks for the link. Reading it now...

Comment: See also https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pandas-dev/2017-November/000657.html; https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pandas-dev/2017-December/000660.html; from the mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is 1 by convention. 1 is the identity operation for products.

I would expect the product of a series to behave as exponentiation, when all numbers in the series are equal. E.g. `product([3,3,3,3]) = 3^4`.
With this reasoning `product([]) = 3^0 = 1`. Lucky for us we don't need to know the base for this case. It seems pandas developers have a similar understanding.

This is also why

> The sum of an empty or all-NA Series is now 0

The empty sum is the identity operation for the sum. Which is 0.

Comment: The sum of an empty list it could reasonably be 0. Still, I don't get why the product of an empty list gives the same result that you can obtain with a list full of 1s. I am reading now about "identity element", quite confusing. Is an identity element a number or a "special type of element" that is not of a number type?

Comment: From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdentityElement.html "The identity element I (also denoted E, e, or 1) of a group or related mathematical structure S is the unique element such that Ia=aI=a for every element a in S. The symbol "E" derives from the German word for unity, "Einheit." An identity element is also called a unit element." So, 1 it's a notation in this case, not the number 1... Or am I wrong?

Comment: For sums think about 2+2+2 which is 2*3. 2 is just 2*1 and  2*0 is 0. That is why the empty sum is 0. Now 2*2*2 can be written as 2^3, 2 as 2^1. But 2^0 is defined as 1. That means 1^1 = 1^0 from which we can induce 1^n=1^0. So your list of full 1s should give you the same result as an empty product. x^0 = 1 is useful for a lot of things. See the Wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: From your linked article it seems the identity elements symbol is also sometimes 1. But for the (scalar) product it is also the *number* one.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. It's much more clear now. I prefer the old way of returning NaN instead of numbers, I have to recheck lots of code now. :(